# Prevent quote expansion in user-made function

Tags: bash, quoting

I have the following bash function :

```
tg() {
  git add -A && git commit -m $1 && git push
}
```

But it seems not to work :

```
$ tg "create index for users"
error: pathspec 'index' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'for' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'users' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Obviously, the problem is that the quote was expanded and my middle command was read as `git commit -m create index for users` rather than `git commit -m "create index for users"`

What did I do wrong ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quote the expansion `$1`:

```
tg() {
  git add -A &&
  git commit -m "$1" &&
  git push
}
```

By not quoting `$1`, the shell will split its value on whitespaces (the contents of `$IFS`) and the resulting words will additionally undergo filename globbing.

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)

Comment: Thx for your help. I'm confused here : isn't "$1" supposed to be a "heredoc" string and variables inside it are supposed to be expanded ? For example, in the shell `echo "$MYVAR"` is equivalent to `echo $MYVAR` ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You are not using any here-document in your code.  A here-document is written `utility <<TAG` and terminated by `TAG` (`TAG` can be any string). It's a form of redirection. `echo $var` and `echo "$var"` are not equivalent for the same reasons as I mentioned in my answer.  Test with `var=*`. When it comes to variable expansions and quoting, `$var` and `$1` behaves the same.

Comment: Got it, thx. I'll  try your solution a few times and accept it if it works.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy  If there's only one "word" and no whitespaces, then `echo "$MYVAR"` and `echo $MYVAR` will have same output. But if you have `hello world` then `"$MYVAR"` is treated as single word, `$MYVAR` is split into two words. In this case, this is trivial. If you do `ls $MYVAR` it can give you file not found if you're looking for `hello world` file, because `ls` will look for two files, `hello` and `world`, but `ls "$MYVAR"` will show you the file `hello world`.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That first sentence is true only given that the word contains no filename globbing characters, and that `IFS` has the default value.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Yep, that too.